# Footer up/down on click

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem regarding my footer position on a click event. I'm working with bootstrap css and I have a collapsible element (accordion in bootstrap) that when collapse it has a class named .accordion-toggle.collapsed and when not his class is .accordion-toggle.

Well, I'm trying to slidedown the footer when this element is collapsed (because it's overwriting the footer) and my code is:

```
<script>
$(function() { 

    var collapsed = $('.accordion-toggle.collapsed');

    $('#links').click(function(){
        if (collapsed){
            $(".footer").css({'margin-top':'320px'});
        }else{
            $(".footer").css({'margin-top':'150px'});
        } 
    });

});
</script>
```

Well the problem is that when I click on the collapsible element the footer slidedown, but when I click again and is not collpased(his class change to (accordion-toggle) the footer doesn't return to his original position that is: 150px margin top.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** Change your javascript to this:

```
var collapsed;
$('#links').click(function () {
    collapsed = $('#links').hasClass('collapsed');
    if (collapsed) {
        $(".footer").css({'margin':'320px 0px 0px 0px'});
    } else {
        $(".footer").css({'margin':'150px 0px 0px 0px'});
    }
});
```

You need to assign a new value to `collapsed` every time `#links` is clicked. Also, jQuery's `.css()` apparently has issues with `margin-top`, so just use `margin` to assign the values.

Comment: `.hasClass('collapsed');` or `.is('.collapsed');`

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I replaced the code but it doesn't work...now it does not slidedown at all :-(...don't know why the footer slidedown (with the original code) but doesn't slideup....

Comment: @dromeo Make a http://jsFiddle.net/ example of your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I put a portion of the code (had to do some changes)...anyway here is working as it should be and without the code...mmhhhh :-( http://jsfiddle.net/GP8MJ/9/

Comment: I think i got the problem: I have a property on the css that is messing up...When i leave the collapsible element on his position is working fine, but when I change the position on the right: float:right the problem appears. http://jsfiddle.net/GP8MJ/19/ any ideas??